# How do I keep an Azure Relay connection alive past the 60 second limit with ASP.NET Core and await?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm using ASP.NET Core (.net 5) and Azure Relay to wrap an on-prem WCF service and expose it externally. My issue is some of the long-running services (60+ seconds) fall outside the 60-sec limit [that Microsoft spelled out here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-protocol).

Somehow, every 60 seconds I need to stream keep alive bytes, but how can I do that with Tasks and await/async calls?

I've managed to identify when tasks DO/DON'T complete within a time limit, but I can't figure out how to keep alive/stream something when it does **not** finish.

I have basically something like:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseAzureRelay(options =>
                {
                    options.UrlPrefixes.Add(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RelayConnectionString"));
                });
```

And in a controller, this is just a heartbeat test that I have sleeping 2 minutes:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetHeartbeatStr")]
    [Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)] // "application/json"
    public async Task<string> GetHeartbeatStr()
    {
        var request = new MyRequest();

        var task = _client.getHeartbeatStrAsync(request);

        var response = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(50000)); // 50 seconds (60 is max)

        if (response == task)
        {
            // Completed within timelimt
            return task.Result.response;
        }
        else
        {
            // Not within timelimit, what do I do?
            // How can I keep the connection alive until the call is complete?
        }
        
        return task.Result.response;
    }
```